# how to while loop fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, while-loop

i would like to loop full screen and i wold like the while loop to wait 3s before it makes the screen full screen agian, heres the code i have:

```
<script>
  function vid() while (true) {
    wait(3)
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    document.getElementById("myVideo").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("everything").style.display = "none";
    doc.requestFullscreen();
    doc.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
</script>
```

this is not working, also if i use a regular while it crashes the webpage.

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to execute code after a delay.

Comment: Don't use a `while(true)` loop, it will lock up the browser.

Comment: then what do i use? btw thx

Comment: Use `setTimeout` like I said.

Comment: no no i mean how do i make a loop with out locking up the browser?

Comment: @hiiiiiiiiii In this case you don't need a loop. Could you explain why you want to implement this loop and what it should do?

Comment: i want a loop that activates a function every 3 seconds for Infinity.

Comment: That can be done using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) which executes a callback function every given milliseconds.

Comment: so how would i use that (sorry im new to coding and olny know some html andcss not js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). `setInterval` works by first passing a `function`. This function will be executed every time the interval is fired. The second parameter is the time between each interval, expressed in milliseconds.

The syntax looks like this.

```
setInterval(function, delay)
```

The example below is an implementing of your code inside the `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(function() {
  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  var everything = document.getElementById("everything");

  vid.style.display = "inline-block";
  everything.style.display = "none";

  doc.requestFullscreen();
  doc.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}, 3000);
```

Its also possible to *reference* the function (and delay) for a more verbose syntax.

```
var delay = 3000;

function forceFullScreen() {
  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  var everything = document.getElementById("everything");

  vid.style.display = "inline-block";
  everything.style.display = "none";

  doc.requestFullscreen();
  doc.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}

setInterval(forceFullScreen, delay);
```

Edit: Result figured out that forcing the user to enter fullscreen won't work. An alternative would be to present a button, listen for a click event and start fullscreen mode whenever the user clicks this button.

Create a button and give it a unique identifier so we know which button to select from JavaScript.

```
<button id="fullscreen">Go into fullscreen mode</button>
```

From JavaScript we'll need to select the button and add an *event listener* for the click event. Then when a click on the button happens, call the function that enables the fullscreen mode.

```
// Select the element (button) with the id fullscreen.
const fullscreenButton = document.getElementById('fullscreen');

function forceFullScreen() {
  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  var everything = document.getElementById("everything");

  vid.style.display = "inline-block";
  everything.style.display = "none";

  doc.requestFullscreen();
  doc.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}

// Listen for the click and call forceFullScreen when a click happens.
fullscreenButton.addEventListener('click', forceFullScreen);
```

Comment: is this what the full code should look like?

  setInterval(function playVid() {
    var e = document.documentElement,
      t = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    (document.getElementById("myVideo").style.display = "inline-block"),
      (document.getElementById("everything").style.display = "none"),
      e.requestFullscreen(),
      e.webkitRequestFullscreen(),
      t.play(),
      (document.title = "Ha Ha ");
  }, 3000);

Comment: Yes. Place it inside a `<script>` tag or as a `.js` file. Place the script before the closing `</body>` tag in your HTML. But to be clear, if your intention is to force fullscreen mode every 3 seconds, then this is what you need. Don't know if the browser will allow it, but I guess we'll soon know ;).

Comment: ok well it worked but i exited full screen with esc and it did not put me back in, also is it posible to start the setInterval onclick?

Comment: That's correct. Browsers are protected against these practices as they disrupt the user experience. So as long as the user doesn't explicitly choose to enter fullscreen mode, for example by clicking a button, it won't work. You can start the `setInterval` on a click event, though you'll still have the same problem with not being able to force the fullscreen mode after the user has decided to leave it. My recommendation would be to lose the interval / loop / forceful code and give the controls to the user. Or at least make it appealing to go to fullscreen mode.

Comment: well can u have js select a button? and make that button put them in full screen?

Comment: Definitely. I've provide another example which demonstrates how this would work.

Comment: thank you for your time i will figure this out thx.

Comment: Sure thing. But you can thank me by accepting the answer as accepted (checkmark top left of the answer).